# Load page in Top frame from iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm using fancybox and I want for it to load a page, and when it does that page checks if it's in the top frame, and if it isn't it reloads itself in the top frame, can anyone tell me how I would achieve this?

This isn't able to be done from a link or form as it's being loaded from the server.

I was given the following code but it didn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function breakout_of_frame(){
        if (top.location != location) {
            parent.location.href = document.location.href ;
        }
    }
    -->
</script>
<body onload="breakout_of_frame()">
```

The trick with this is that the page that I'm wanting to check if it's in the iFrame is the same page as the top frame

Comment: do you mean that the page should break out of fancybox and load on top of the page? If so, what is the idea to load it in fancybox?

Comment: @JFK I'm loading pages in the fancybox, but if there is an error it redirects back to the original page, so I want it to break out and display the page again properly with the error displayed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword `top` to refer to the highest level frame, and `self` which refers to the frame that contains the current document:

```
function breakout_of_frame() {
  if(top !== self) {
     top.location.href = location.href;
  }
}
```